# Identity works fine on localhost but having errors on server

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I am using .Net Core MVC with built-in authorization for individual user accounts. 
Registration and login works fine when I run it locally but when I uploaded it on Smarterasp and tried to register I got an error saying :

> An error occurred while processing your request.

This is my publishing profile

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>website.com</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectGuid>501f4fbc-faa5-4f41-859b-177881cbb611</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>https://website.com:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=coinmaniabot-001-site1</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>sitename</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>False</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>coinmaniabot-001</UserName>
    <AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>
    <_SavePWD>False</_SavePWD>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Any stacktrace available?

Comment: for publishing you need to create a self-signed certificate first and address it in your code